# Getting the smallest possible integer ratio between two numbers

Tags: java

I wrote this code to find the smallest possible integer ratio between two numbers:

```
void ratio(int a, int b) {
    int min = Math.min(a, b);
    int max = Math.max(a, b);
    if(max % min == 0) {
               System.out.println("1" + " " + max / min);
               return;
        }
    for (int i = 2; i <= min; i++) {
        while(max % i == 0 && min % i == 0) {
            max /= i;
            min /= i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max + " " + min);
}
```

Is there any better/efficient way to do this? Am I missing any good algorithm?

Comment: are you referring to GCD (Greatest Common Divisor)?

Comment: You're basically talking about finding and eliminating all of the common divisors.  Look for algorithms for that.  (Note that your algorithm above unnecessarily visits even divisors after eliminating 2.)

Comment: I think, this code is efficient enough...

Comment: NO.. for example in GCD, the GCD between 480 & 800 is 1 but in my case I want to know the smallest possible integer ratio like ratio of 480 & 800 is 3:5.The function has to return the two number(3 & 5)

Comment: The GCD between 480 and 800 is at least 40.  You can tell that much from simple inspection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to find the [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and then divide both numbers by that.

[Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Background_.E2.80.94_Greatest_common_divisor) is the classic way to do this.

```
int gcd(int p, int q) {
    if (q == 0) return p;
    else return gcd(q, p % q);
}

void ratio(int a, int b) {
   final int gcd = gcd(a,b);
   System.out.println(a/gcd + " " + b/gcd);
}
```

If you want to swap `a` and `b` to have the biggest first then that's easy too

```
void ratio(int a, int b) {
   final int gcd = gcd(a,b);
   if(a > b) {
       showAnswer(a/gcd, b/gcd);
   } else {
       showAnswer(b/gcd, a/gcd);
   }
}

void showAnswer(int a, int b) {
   System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
```

Comment: I thought about Euclid once but somehow rejected it while coding :(
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: It's an oldie but a goodie... (written in c.300BC it's over 2300 years old).